# SQLITE_MISUSE: bad parameter or other API misuse

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am getting an sqlite error when following [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/).

I have installed the Windows ODBC driver and did an `npm install sqlite3` in the project and global `npm install`

```
$ node src/script.js
SQLITE_MISUSE: bad parameter or other API misuse
```

The script is

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./project.db', sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
        console.log('Connected to the project database.');
    }
});
```

Everything I read about sqlite says that even the OPEN_CREATE statement shouldn't be necessary, it should create the db file if it doesn't exist. When I run the script no db file is created, just causes the error message. Why won't sqlite make this db file for me?

Comment: Removing the `OPEN_CREATE`, and thus using the default of `OPEN_READWRITE | OPEN_CREATE`, worked for me (after your code produced the same error).